# Reshape a bufferedImage and store the double values in txt

Tags: java, bufferedimage, reshape

I want to load an image to resize it to 100x100 to reshape it in 1x100000 and save it in an txt file. So I read it in bufferedImage, I resize it to 100x100. The next steps for reshaping it and save the double values of it is what I am looking for:

```
            File img = new File(train_path + fileNames.get(i) + "/" + imageNames.get(i).get(j));
            BufferedImage in = ImageIO.read(img);
            BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(in.getWidth(), in.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
            Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(in, 0, 0, null);
            g.dispose();

            BufferedImage newImg = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

            Graphics gr = newImg.createGraphics();
            gr.drawImage(newImage, 0, 0, 100, 100, null);
            gr.dispose();
            System.out.println(newImage.getHeight()+ " "+ newImage.getWidth());
            System.out.println(newImg.getHeight()+ " "+ newImg.getWidth());
```

Comment: By reshape you mean you just want it to become a linear array? Do you ever need the reshaped image, apart from saving its contents to a file?

Comment: I want to reshape it as a vector and store it in a txt. Basically I ve got 500 images and I want to do the same process for all of them to have finally 500x10000 matrix or lower which is depends on the resize factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an array of `int` from the initial image:

```
int[] pixels = newImage.getRGB(0, 0, 100, 100, null, 0, 100);
```

which means get RGB values from (0,0) to (100,100) in a new array, starting from index 0, offsetting index for each line of 100.

Then for each `int` in `pixels`, the grayscale value is given by:

```
int gray = pixels[i] & 0xFF;
```

Comment: You mean from the resized newImg?

Comment: No, because you are cropping the image as you do this, so you can skip that step... well, try ;-)

Comment: Basically its indeed cropping. I want to resize the initital image to 100x1000. When I println pixels, it shows me:
-1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 -1118482 ....

Comment: Why not? those are the ARGB values, try taking only the rightmost byte with `argb & 0xff`

Comment: But I defined BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY

Comment: You did. But the `getRGB` method is nonetheless returning you ARGB values. Basically it's making the R, G and B part equal, so the final result is gray. At least, that's the way I understand it